# exporting bash paths with same variable name

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm looking at my bash profile and not really understanding what I see. I think I see a variable (PATH) being redeclared - though this can't be true as all my programs seem to work. Can you help me by talking me through what is going on?

here is part of my bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.phpenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(phpenv init -)"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

#Added for mysql installation by me
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands are run sequentially, each adding the previous value of `$PATH` to the end of the new path part. For example, if the value of `$PATH` right before line 5 is

```
"~/.phpenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

then the right-hand side of line 5 it will be expanded to

```
"/usr/local/heroku/bin:~/.phpenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

and `$PATH` will be overwritten with this new value.

Comment: thanks. I'm still not sure how that is working. what does the colon do?

Comment: @ZachSmith: It does nothing; it's merely part of the value. (The syntax of a `$PATH` value is a colon-delimited list of directories.)

Comment: ok thanks. so then that is a list of paths? so then i guess I have one more question :p. how do applications know which path value to use or do they just cycle through them until they find one that works?

Comment: Yes, your shell starts from the beginning of the list and runs the first executable file it finds with the name of the command you typed.